# Alexa Skill Certification Validation Errors

Tags: validation, alexa-skills-kit

When i go to the "Validation" Tab it says:

[image]

When i go to the "Distribution --> Privacy & Compliance" Tab all those things have a selected answer as you can see on the picture.
[image]

Does anybody know how to solve these problems?

Any help would be great :)

(Feel free to move this topic to a better place in the forum.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to make sure these details are there and are saved. Then run the validation again and this should not happen. Maybe you are seeing the previous validation results.

Comment: Looks like you were right. After re-running the validation the errors disapeared. Thx for help